# Entering many Values into a sql database at one

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Question:

I have a table with 100 rows called user
I am after creating a new table called village and I would like to have it automatically fill in 100 rows in the new table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a select to full records of your new table like this

```
insert into village (user_id, owner)
select id, username
from `user`
```

Comment: Thanks and how would I add second value like so i have the id but i want owner in village to be the same as username from user

Comment: Bad idea having the username in the village table.  It gives you two records to maintain in case buddy changes his name.  You can always get the name by joining the two tables.